# Access Log files using Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, soa, oracle-fusion-middleware

I would like to access diagnostic log files of our server using weblogic console.

originally, the logs are located here:
/u01/projects/domains/prd_soa_domain/servers/prd_soa_ms1/logs

where should i put it so that i can access/download them thru my browser something like this.

http:ip address:port/console/logs/

Answer (score 1):

These logs are already available to you, navigate to:

```
Admin Console -> Diagnostics -> Log Files
```

Here you can view JMS Logs, Data Source Logs, Server Logs, etc.

If you're talking about the Default Audit logs, you can set the path for all of those files to go to the same directory. Check this [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/security_defaultauditor_general.html) And if you're interested in tuning it further, check this [tutorial](http://jvzoggel.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/weblogic-domain-audit/).